# PHP mySQL one-to-many get result as an array

Tags: php, mysql, join, one-to-many

I have 3 tables, one of which is used to store general properties of items. Each item can get one or more images and one or more addresses, which I store in separate tables.

tbl_items

```
id    title
1     item1
2     item2
```

tbl_item_imgs

```
id  title  filename  item_id
1   img1   kfm.gif   1
2   img2   edff.png  1
3   img3   knkk.jpg  2
4   img4   lkj.png   1
```

tbl_item_addresses

```
id  address     attitude   longitude  item_id
1   texas       55         54         1
2   NY          34         34         1
3   texas       55         53.5       1
4   LA          84         85         2
```

Now I want to get an array or object as a result like this:

```
array(2){

   [0]=> array(4){
          [id]=>"1"
          [title]=>"item1"
          [imgs] => array(3){
               [0]=> array(4){
                   [id] => "1"
                   [title] => "img1"
                   [filename] => "kfm.gif"
                   [item_id] => "1" 
               }
               [1]=> array(4){
                   [id] => "2"
                   [title] => "img2"
                   [filename] => "edff.png"
                   [item_id] => "1" 
               }
               [2]=> array(4){
                   [id] => "4"
                   [title] => "img"
                   [filename] => "lkj.png"
                   [item_id] => "1" 
               }
          }
          [addresses] = array(3){
              [0]=> array(4){
                   [id] => "1"
                   [address] => "texas"
                   [attitude] => "55"
                   [longitude] => "54" 
               }
               [1]=> array(4){
                   [id] => "2"
                   [address] => "NY"
                   [attitude] => "34"
                   [longitude] => "34" 
               }
               [2]=> array(4){
                   [id] => "3"
                   [address] => "texas"
                   [attitude] => "55"
                   [longitude] => "53.5" 
               }
          }        
   }

   [1]=> array(4){
      array(4){
          [id]=>"1"
          [title]=>"item1"
          [imgs] => array(1){
              [0]=>array(4){
                   [id] => "3"
                   [title] => "img3"
                   [filename] => "knkk.jpg"
                   [item_id] => "2" 
              }    
          }
          [addresses] = array(1){
              [0]=>array(4){
                   [id] => "4"
                   [address] => "LA"
                   [attitude] => "84"
                   [longitude] => "85"
              }
          }
       }
   }

}
```

So, my question is this: Can I do this via one sql request? I am aware that mysql does not return array so I have to process the mysql result with php to get this. Please help me to find out the best way to do this.

One way might be to get the items with one query and foreach through them, then get the addresses and imgs of each row  with separate sql requests and push them into item array. I don't think this is a good idea because that requires too many queries and would be slow.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're asking: If you can pull all that data with one SQL query (and if so, what that query is) or how you go about making an array out of that data.

Comment: I would use two joins to get the data from the database. I would then use a foreach with the item id as a key for the parent array and I would push the address data and img data to the array through a loop.

Comment: @MartinE. Care to give the OP some code?

Comment: I suppose I could surely do that... I was hoping there was an attempt to figure it out but yeah... I can do that... (it will be in mysql because the server my work uses doesn't support mysqli... SAD SAD Day!)

Answer (score 2):

```
    <?php
        $current_title = '';
        $data_array = array();
        $query = "SELECT tbl_items.*, imgs.id AS image_id,imgs.title AS image_title,imgs.filename AS image_filename,imgs.item_id AS image_itemid , addresses.item_id AS address_itemid, addresses.id AS address_id
        , addresses.attitude AS address_attitude, addresses.longitude AS address_longitude
            FROM tbl_items
            LEFT JOIN tbl_items_addresses AS addresses ON tbl_items.id = addresses.item_id
            LEFT JOIN tbl_item_imgs AS imgs ON tbl_items.id = imgs.item_id";
        $data_results = mysql_query($query);
        foreach ($data_results as $data){
            if ($data['title'] != $current_title){
                $current_title = $data['title'];
                $data_array[$current_title]['id'] = $data['id'];
                $data_array[$current_title]['title'] = $data['title'];
                $data_array[$current_title]['addresses'] = array();
                $data_array[$current_title]['imgs'] = array();
            }
                $data_array[$current_title]['addresses'][] = ('address_id'=>$data['address_id'],'address_itemid'=>$data['address_itemid'],'address_attitude'=>$data['address_attitude'],'address_longitude'=>$data['address_longitude']);
                $data_array[$current_title]['imgs'][] = ('image_id'=>$data['image_id'],'image_title'=>$data['image_title'],'image_filename'=>$data['image_filename'],'image_itemid'=>$data['image_itemid']);
        }
    ?>
```

Comment: There you go @Nigel Nquande :) there is probably better ways to do it but thats how I would do it!